# How view gets fully visible in scene in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qgraphicsview, qgraphicsscene

I am having QGraphicsView, which has multiple QGraphicsItem's.
When my design loads first time and gets visible on screen, it can not be fit fully in the screen. Around 80% of view gets visible. Then I need to use scrolling to see the remaining 20% of the view.

> How my whole design will get visible at the time of loading ?

```
myClass::myClass(QWidget* parent) :
    QDockWidget(parent)

{
   hide();
   QWidget* newWidget = new QWidget();
   QBoxLayout* tLayout = new QBoxLayout(QBoxLayout::TopToBottom,newWidget );
   tLayout->setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);

   QLabel *label = new QLabel("My Window",this);
   this->setTitleBarWidget(label);
   tbar = new QToolBar;
   tbar->setIconSize(QSize(35,35));
   tbar->setToolButtonStyle(Qt::ToolButtonTextUnderIcon);
   tLayout->addWidget(tbar,0,Qt::AlignTop);          

   QGraphicsScene* scene = new QGraphicsScene(this);
   QGraphicsView* view = new QGraphicsView(this);
   view->setScene(scene);             

   tLayout->addWidget(view);
   newWidget ->setLayout(tLayout);

   bar = new QStatusBar();
   bar->showMessage(tr("Ready"));
   this->setWidget(bar);

   setWidget(newWidget);
}
```

I was told , how to proceed ( but not sure I understood properly ) : 1st find out the points through `scene->sceneRect()` then take 2 points , top right and bottom left and use some `margin` function and add some margin to it and then give those 2 points to `ensureVisibility()` which will make visible those points.
How to achieve this ?

Comment: Why not to call `setFixedSize` on the view, after you add all items to the scene, and you know the size of bounding rect of all added items -> returned by `scene->sceneRect()` ?

Comment: @rafix07 I added these lines after addition of all the items. `QRectF a = _scene->sceneRect();`  `_view->setFixedSize(a.x(),a.y());`    But my view is blank. Nothing is there. Where am I wrong ?

Comment: Instead of `a.x(),a.y()` it should be `a.width(),a.height()`.

Comment: @rafix07 It worked. But if your view has large height, then it adjust window size according to that. And if another view ( I am opening in another tab) is small then large empty space gets visible. Because it follows height according to large view. So can we zoom out large view and will make it small according to window and then fit it in window ?

Comment: @rafix07  Window size should not change. View should get zoom in or zoom out according to window. Is this possible ?

Comment: @rafix07 I was told , how to proceed ( but not sure I understood properly ) : 1st find out the points through `scene->sceneRect()`  then take 2 points ,  top right and bottom left and use some `margin`  function and add some margin to it and then  give those 2 points to `ensureVisibility` which will make visible those points.  Is this proper way  ?

Comment: @rafix07  sorry but I dont know correct function but `sceneRect`, `margin` and then `ensure` I remember.  Are you getting any clue out of it ?

Comment: @rafix07  I did like this :  (After adding all the item in a view )   `QRectF a = scene->sceneRect();`   `view->ensureVisible(a,100,100);`    But still view is not fully visible. Can you help me in this ?